# Use secp384r1 PEM key to sign a Verifiable Credential with Linked Data proofs

Tags: public-key, elliptic-curves

Ok, let me preface this by clarifying that I am not a cryptographer by trade, but I've been using cryptographic suites in the context of signing w3c Verifiable Credentials, and I am not sure if this is the right place to ask this question.

In the European framework, eIDAS requires Qualified eSeals for legal entities.

We managed to get our hands on such an eSeal, but it was generated with an EC secp384r1 algorithm.

At this moment there is no Linked Data Proof library that handles this algorithm, but others are available (for instance Ed25519Signature2020, EcdsaSecp256k1Signature2019, ...).

I'm wondering how people with more experience in cryptography would approach the problem here, which is basically sign a document with the eSeal and have it verifiable with self contained public keys (ie: through a did:key verification method)?

Is creating an LD proof library the only way?

Comment: OpenSSL provides a crypto library in addition to implementing the SSL/TLS protocol.